# Using EE Search with Store

Tags: expresso-store, simple-search

I'm using EE2's simple search like so.

```
{exp:search:simple_form result_page="search" search_in="title" status="open" channel="gg_store"}
     <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="keywords" placeholder="Search" />
     <input type="submit" id="searchSubmit" name="searchSubmit" value="GO" />
{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

and my search results, using {exp:store:product} looks like this...

```
{exp:search:search_results}
                {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}
                    <div id="product-list">
                        <span class="itemtitle"><a href="{url_title_path='/the-collection/product-detail/'}">{title}</a></span>
                        <a href="{url_title_path='/the-collection/product-detail/'}">{gallery_image_1} <img src="{path}_252x252/{filename}.{extension}" width="100%" /> {/gallery_image_1}</a><br />
                        <?php echo StringLimiter('{e_comm_body}','160'); ?>
                        <br /><br />
                        <div style="float:right;">
                            <span class="BTN updateBTN">
                                <a href="{url_title_path='/{e_comm_type}/product-detail/'}">Learn More...</a>
                            </span>
                        </div><!-- //control-group -->
                        {if on_sale}
                            <del>{regular_price}</del>
                            <span class="price">{price}</span>
                        {if:else}
                            <span class="price">{price}</span>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                {/exp:store:product}
        {/exp:search:search_results}
```

Here's my "issue", this works 90% of the time. I'm building a website that sells only a few items. They are stored in the gg_store channel.

If i search a term like mma, pads, shin, it seems to be working properly. But for whatever reason, certain terms throw a weird EE error.
Terms like Gloves, Gear... and this is the error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /system/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php(683) : eval()'d code on line 321
```

I did narrow down, the reason that causes it... it's {e_comm_type}. If i remove that all of a sudden every search term i can think of starts working.
{e_comm_type} is a custom field which stores info like "The Collection", "Victory Athletics", "Apparel".

Any idea's why and how to fix this? I need to use {e_comm_type} to properly set the url destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a parse order bug. Unfortunately, there's not much you can do except work around it (unless you want to report it to EL, but I wouldn't hold your breath waiting for a fix :).

I would try putting the search result display template code into an embed, and passing through the variables you need. This solves 90% of parse order issues I've seen.

Something like this:

```
{exp:search:search_results}
    {embed="embed/.search_result"}
{/exp:search:search_results}
```

Comment: Hmmm i'll give that a go later today. Thanks!

Comment: This ended up being the way i did it after-all. It worked well.